# Is it possible to decrypt with public key using openssl's EVP api

Tags: c, openssl

All the examples I found in the documentation are `encrypt with public key and then decrypt with private key`.

Therefore, can I decrypt with a public key, using EVP_XXX api? Or the only way to decrypt with public key is using RSA_XXX api?

Any answer is welcome.

Comment: If people can decrypt data with a public key then that kind of defeats the purpose of encryption don't you think

Comment: @GillBates Yes, it is a strange operation. But for some reason, we need it now. Anyway, it can be done with `RSA_public_decrypt`, just wonder if there is an equal in EVP api.(Because the codebase is built above EVP api, I just want to follow the style).

Comment: [The documentation says](https://linux.die.net/man/3/rsa_public_decrypt) `RSA_public_decrypt() recovers the message digest from the flen bytes long signature at from using the signer's public key rsa.` - That's not decryption.

Comment: What you might want is to decrypt a signature. Bob calculates the hash of a given payload, then encrypts it using his private key, generating a signature that can be verified. He sends everything to Alice. Then using his public key, Alice can decrypt that signature and validate it by matching against the hash she calculates over the payload she received from Bob. If both hashes match, then she can trust that the payload was not tampered and was indeed sent by someone that has access to Bob's private key.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to decrypt with public key using openssl's EVP api

No. Its not a valid cryptographic operation. You won't be able to do it with most security libraries, like Botan, Crypto++ or OpenSSL.

> Therefore, can I decrypt with a public key, using EVP_XXX api? Or the only way to decrypt with public key is using RSA_XXX api?

Usually folks want a [Signature Scheme with Recovery](https://www.google.com/search?q=Signature+Scheme+with+Recovery) when they start asking for "encrypt with private key" and "decrypt with public key" questions. But we don't know what your use case is, so we can't really make a recommendation.

Asking for cryptosystem recommendations is probably off-topic for Stack Overflow. Maybe you should describe your problem and seek guidance on [Cryptography Stack Exchange](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/).